# Flask - When Using logging.handlers.HTTPHandler to post errors can you redirect or flash these errors?

Tags: python, flask

I have a logger that is used throughout my system and reports back errors using the HTTP handler and then flask catches them and I want to be able to flash them so the user can see the error.

I am specifically and intentionally not using flasks normal logger as it needs to extend throughout my system so errors are properly logged.

However, although flask seems to catch the errors and can print them out from the logs view it is unable to flash them to the user or redirect to a page that would display them.

Here is the relevant section of my setup of my handler/logger:

```
'error_handler': {
    'class': 'logging.handlers.HTTPHandler',
    'formatter': 'debug_formatter',
    'level': 'WARNING',
    'filters': ['Web_filter'],
    'host': 'localhost:5000',
    'url' : '/logs',
    'method' : 'POST',
},
```

And here is the view that catches those errors:

```
@app.route('/logs' , methods = ["GET","POST"])
def logs():
    message = str(request.form['message'])
    print("message: " + message) #this works
    flash(message) #this doesn't
    return render_template('500_unhandled.html', title='ERROR', e = message) #neither does this
```

UPDATE: I actually switched the method of creating the logger so it is a little simpler but it still does not work:

```
 http_handler = HTTPHandler('localhost:5000','/logs',method='POST',)
 http_handler.addFilter(WebFilter())
 new_logger.addHandler(http_handler)
```

UPDATE2: I tried the suggestion to just return message but that left me questioning where I would even access this returned value so some more help there would be appreciated here is that version:

```
@app.route('/logs' , methods = ["GET","POST"])
def logs():
    message = str(request.form['message'])
    print("message: " + message) #this works
    return message #this doesn't really do anything
```

I also tried using the abort method:

```
@app.route('/logs' , methods = ["GET","POST"])
def logs():
    message = str(request.form['message'])
    print("message: " + message) #this works
    abort(500, message) #this doesn't work either
```

UPDATE3:
I added a logging message into the view function just to see if it was for some reason being called from a different location or thread that was blocking communication. Here are the two different logging messages and the code that generated them:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    logger.error('test error')

Prints: 
   routes:Thread-1:test error

@app.route('/logs' , methods = ["GET","POST"])
def logs():
    message = str(request.form['message'])
    logger.info("where am i?")
    print("message: " + message) #this works
    abort(500, message)

Prints: 
routes:Thread-2:where am i?
message: test error
```

Is the fact that they are in different threads problematic or is this normal?

UPDATE4: Another weird thing I just noticed is I can't access the session variables from the logs view. This is making me think for some reason logs is acting as separately from the rest of the app.

UPDATE5: Just to reiterate something I mentioned in the comments that is super weird the abort statement works and redirects to my error handler but the error page "500.html" only flashes on the screen before I am redirected to the home page. here is the code for my error handler:

```
@app.errorhandler(500)
def handle_500(e):
    original = getattr(e, "original_exception", None)
    if original is None:
        # direct 500 error, such as abort(500)
        print(e)
        return render_template("500.html",e = e), 500
    # wrapped unhandled error
    return render_template("500_unhandled.html", e=original), 500
```

Comment: Have you tried commenting out `flash(message)` and just using `return message`?

Comment: I tried that due to your suggestion please see my update for more details.

Comment: Are you using this https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#httphandler?

Comment: Yes I am using that @fcsr

Comment: Cool replied with an answer

Answer (score 1):

When you call `logger.info()` it sends `POST` request with message to your server and view function `logs()` handles this request. It gets message, prints it, flashes it and returns page to the logger request. Thus, message is printed.

When you access this page in browser, browser sends `GET` request without message to your server, once again view function `logs()` handles this request. It tries to get message, but there is no message in the request. So it doesn't get printed nor flashed.

To display messages you need to store them somewhere. Add messages to the database/array/file/etc when you get `POST` request. Retrieve messages when you get `GET` request and flash them, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your response, however, I think this is incorrect. Firstly, when the `POST` request is handled it does not flash or redirect it will only print this is the crux of my post. Secondly, I never attempt to access the log view through the browser it is meant to just handle the requests as the come in and is not a page in of itself to prove this I removed the `GET` method from it entirely and the functionality was the same.

Comment: How do you know that when `POST` request is handled message does not get flashed or you are not redirected? Response is sent to the logger and logger is not displaying it - so you can not see flashed message nor template/redirection. When next request is made and response is sent, it already does not contain flashed message as flashed messages live only during 1 response. Also why were you using render_template() if you did not want to access this page through the browser?

Comment: Also why are you using HTTPHandler and sending requests with log messages to you server - overloading it. Simply write your own handler which will flash messages and everything will work.

Comment: I know that the flashing doesn't work because originally I was just returning nothing and not redirecting or anything meaning everything was still in the same request. I added the render template statement just to see if it would work as an option. I can tell I am not redirecting properly because if I call return redirect to a different page than the one where the error originated from I am still returned to the original page. I am using HTTP handler so that multiple different loggers throughout my system can all send their messages to the same place.

Comment: I guess I could use a file to do this but it seems like I should be able to do it this way and I don't know why it doesn't work. Just to add I also tried using abort and that seemed to raise the error properly but I was also not redirected to the designated error page.

Comment: Thank you for all your help by the way. I just checked by doing `print(request.method)` and I am definitely accessing it using `POST`

Comment: To conclude, it does not work, because flashed messages live exactly during one response, so message lives during the response which is made to the handler. And when you from the browser make next request to any page and get response, message is already deleted. The redirect does not work for you as handler gets redirected and not you. So, handler gets both redirection and message and you cannot see it.

Comment: Well thats not true though because its not just a problem of the flashed message not appearing for instance if I store the message in the session variable and try to access it elsewhere it doesn't exist. And the session exists throughout all requests.

Comment: So, the problem is not only in this but also, that logger gets different session.

Comment: Yeah thats what is strange. Something I tried and noticed because of your advice about not being able to tell if I was redirected was putting a print in my error handler view to see if the abort statement was working and it is! but the error page only flashes on the screen before I'm returned to the home page. It doesn't seem to halt the currently executing code as it should.

Answer (score 0):

**SEE EDIT BELOW FOR BETTER ANSWER**

I'm not sure if I understood this question clearly, but I'll give it a shot.

Your problem sounds like an HTML problem. Flashing requires you add a provision for flashing in the HTML template you return: you must specify in your returned HTML that it must display your flashed message:

Example HTML:

```
<h1>My HTML title</h1>
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
    {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
            <p>{{ message }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

The `get_flashed_messages()` method provided by Flask gets all flashed messages, which are returned through the template. Without this flashing WILL NOT WORK!

Second, your python code must make flashed messages avaliable. `flash()` methods serve as a temporary holding location for messages and will disappear after they are viewed in **any** page that displays them. Whether this is okay, you decide.

Redirect or return an HTML template containing a way to view these flashed messages:

```
@app.route('/logs' , methods = ["GET","POST"])
def logs():
    message = str(request.form['message'])
    flash(message)
    return render_template('contains_flash.html')
```

This template (in this case, `contains_flash.html`) must be contained in a /templates folder in your project's directory to be accessed properly, and must contain something like the previous HTML code.

Finally, make sure that you add separate parts in your function that handle POST requests vs just regular viewing of the page:

```
@app.route('/logs' , methods = ["GET","POST"])
def logs():
    if request.method == "POST":
        message = str(request.form['message'])
        flash(message)
        # goes back to same page so user can view messages
        return redirect(url_for('logs')) 
    else:
        # perhaps flashes messages and has form to POST messages
        return render_template('contains_flash.html')
```

Keep in mind that for all of the above code, the user must arrive at `your-url/logs` to access your logs (flashed messages).

Finally, to explain the return statement suggested: ie `return message`. If you used `return message`, it would display the HTML equivalent of the message when a user went to 'url/log`. So it would return your message but without any HTML formatting.

**EDIT:** An answer taking into account more of the question.

Because `flash()` stores separate data for each user session, flashed messages will not be seen by users. Thus, flashing obviously doesn't work. Printing works, because the message is not being accessed by you in your web browser (in a different session), but instead just being printed into a terminal where you can see it.

Instead, use a database to store the logged messages and then show them to users. A fairly easy to setup database would be [`sqlite3`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html), which you could use.

```
import sqlite3
# ... previous code

conn = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite') # your db name
conn.row_factory = lambda cursor, row: row[0] # does not return tuple
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS errors
         (message TEXT NOT NULL)''') # create table
conn.commit() # saves database operations

@app.route('/logs' , methods = ["GET","POST"])
def logs():
    if request.method == "POST":
        message = str(request.form['message'])
        c.execute('INSERT INTO errors (message) VALUES (?)', (message,))
        conn.commit()

    # if not a POST, request must be from user:
    errors = c.execute('SELECT message FROM errors').fetchall() # get all messages: this can be changed
    return render_template('messages.html', errors=errors)
```

messages.html displays errors:

```
<h1>Errors below</h1>
{% for error in errors %}
    <p>{{ error }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Now, the above should work as a simple way to store logged errors. Add more fields to the table as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of how the HTTPHandler class works.
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d4a63031dac0078d97677da43a1e3004ea64c993/Lib/logging/handlers.py#L1199

It will emit your error message to your `/log` endpoint. And the log endpoint returns the rendered html with your message to the logger. But then the logger can't do anything with it. It doesn't return the value to your user's browser. So nothing appears.

Relevant line for the class. Its even mentioned that it can't do anything with the result.
 `h.getresponse()    #can't do anything with the result`